# How to calculate number of authors in EPrints (repository like DSpace)?

Tags: perl, repository, citations

EPrints is a perl-based repository, see [EPrints in WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPrints)

My librarian asked me to setup EPrins in the following way (only for the "monograph" type of documents):

1. If there are 3 or less authors then print 'authors' before title of the monograph;
2. If there more than 3 authors then print '$title / $authors'.

For example, 7 authors in first publication and 2 authors in second publication:

1. *Analysis of the quotation corpus of the Russian Wiktionary* / **Smirnov A., Levashova T., Karpov A., Kipyatkova I., Ronzhin A., Krizhanovsky A., Krizhanovsky N.** Research in Computing Science. 2012
2. *Meyer C. M., Gurevych I.* **Worth its Weight in Gold or Yet Another Resource - A Comparative Study of Wiktionary, OpenThesaurus and GermaNet**. 2010.

Answer (score 1):

After several ours of try-and-fail attempts... The big problem is that EPrints is not pure Perl, and there are not too much documentation...

We need to edit the **citations** file /eprints/cfg/citations/eprint/default.xml). There is the following solution:

```xml
<!-- Monograph: if < 4 authors then print 'authors' before title -->
<when test="type = 'monograph'">

      <if test="is_set(creators_name)"> 

          <set name='authors' expr="creators_name">
              (Debug information) Number of authors: 
              <print expr="$authors.length()"/>.

              <set name='authors_len' expr="$authors.length()">

                  <if test="$authors_len lt 4">
                      <print expr="creators_name"/>
                  </if>
              </set>
          </set>
      </if> 
</when>

<!-- Title -->
<cite:linkhere><xhtml:em><print expr="title"/>:</xhtml:em></cite:linkhere>


<!-- "/ authors" after Title for monography if len(authors)>3 -->
<choose>
  <when test="type = 'monograph'">

      <if test="is_set(creators_name)"> 

          <set name='authors' expr="creators_name">
              <set name='authors_len' expr="$authors.length()">

                  <if test="$authors_len gt 3">
                     / <print expr="creators_name"/>
                  </if>

              </set>
          </set>
      </if>
  </when>

  <otherwise>
  </otherwise>
</choose>
```

It works, but... I calculated twice the same variable "authors_len". And I don't know how to reuse this variable and calculate it only once.

I tried the EPrints function "is_set(authors_len)" and I tried "is_set($authors_len)", but EPrints throws different error messages o_O

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following, checking for the creators_name being set, and how many creators there are:

```xml
<when test="type = 'monograph'">
  <choose>
    <when test="is_set(creators_name) and length(creators_name) lt 4">
      <print expr="creators_name" />
      / 
      <print expr="title" />
    </when>
    <when test="is_set(creators_name) and length(creators_name) gt 3">
      <print expr="title" />
      /
      <print expr="creators_name" />
    </when>
    <otherwise>
      <print expr="title" />
    </otherwise>
  </choose>
</when>
```

When using XML comments in an EPrints citation file, they will appear in the HTML source of the page. To make comments in the citation file that do not appear in the html source, you can use:

```xml
<comment>This will not appear in the html source</comment>
```

The language used for EPrints citations is documented on the EPrints Wiki:

- https://wiki.eprints.org/w/EPScript
- https://wiki.eprints.org/w/EPrints_Control_Format

Some XML configuration files use different default namespaces - so you may see the elements prefixed with a namespace e.g.

```xml
<cite:citation xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns="http://eprints.org/ep3/control" xmlns:cite="http://eprints.org/ep3/citation" >
  ...
  <epc:comment>This is a comment</epc:comment>
  ...
</cite:citation>
```

The best place for assistance with EPrints is their Mailing list - search the wiki (linked above) for details (I don't have enough reputation to post another link!).